# create the folders in perl

Tags: regex, perl

```
open my$fh,"/home/httpd/cgi-bin/r/ex1.txt";
while(my$line = <$fh> ){mkdir "$line";}
```

my query is to create directories for above `list(exr1.txt)`. i get output on the same location but i need to create directories for above `list(ex1.txt)` at different location. How can i create code for that?

Comment: It seems your space key is not working.

Comment: You'll need a `chomp` in there at the very least.

Comment: You will probable want to use `make_path()` from `File::Path`. See `perldoc File::Path` http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Path.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try using `chdir`?

```
use autodie;
open my $fh, "/home/httpd/cgi-bin/r/ex1.txt";
chdir "different location";
while ( my $line = <$fh> ) {
    chomp $line;
    mkdir $line;
}
```